# iOS push notifications works on Debug but not on Release

Tags: ios, google-app-engine, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have iOS app with GAE backend. I'm receiving notifications on device with debug build but not with release build. I have enabled the Push notification for Distribution in iOS App IDs. I have downloaded the latest provisioning profiles.
Am I missing something or not enabled for distribution?

Comment: Did you try and receive messages if you use a Push Notification Service testing tool? Like [this one](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/easy-apns-provider-push-notification/id989622350?mt=12)

Comment: Are you using adhoc distribution for checking release push notifications?@SpyZip

Comment: Why do I need to test with the tool when I can use the actual backend, it works with the debug version with no error. 
I use App store distribution not adhok.

Comment: Has the backend switched over from using the Apple non-sandbox environment to the sandbox environment? Has the backend switched from using the development ssl certificate to the production one? Is the push token programmatically obtained using the production build of the app?

Comment: Good questions. I don't know the answers. I'm following the GAE documentation, Now I'll migrate to Firebase and see if I have missed something in the way.